# Click event / bind event not working in jQuery when generating buttons in Mustache JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, mustache

I have a button which is generated in a function via a mustache JS template.

```
{{#attributes}}
    <a class="button--small btn" data-selector="{{selector}}">{{title}}</a>
{{/attributes}}
```

and a sample output of that is

```
<a class="button--small btn" data-selector=".news">More News</a>
```

However, I am trying to execute another `jquery` function when this button is clicked but regardless of whether I use `.click(function() { });` or `.bind` it doesn't seem to work? Even a `console.log` doesn't print so I'm not getting into the right conditions.

Here is the script:

```
function lazyload(selector) {
    $("a[data-selector^='"+selector+"']").bind("click", function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            loadNews(selector);
    });
}

$(document).ready(function(){
   lazyload(".news"); // CALL FUNCTION READY FOR USAGE
});
```

Comment: It might be easier to simply make "news" a class rather than a data. Then you could do `$(".news")...` etc. Also `.bind` is deprecated, you should use `.on` instead (same method signature). Lastly, are your `<a>` elements loaded at page load, or later on? If they're later, you need to use the version of `.on` which supports delegated events (see the jQuery docs) http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For newly created elements you need to delegate the [event](http://api.jquery.com/on/): see "Direct and delegated events" section.

```
function lazyload(selector) {
   $(document).on("click", "a[data-selector^='"+selector+"']", function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        loadNews(selector);
   });
 }
```

Comment: Brilliant - thanks mate 1 min till I can accept

Comment: You made my day!!!! :) Thanks a lot!!!